# Cannot Apply display:block to div set to display:none

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've a question, I'm trying to structure a site so that when it is in desktop mode a particular `div` which contains an `img` element is set to `display:none`;

When the screen size gets to `450px` or less I would like to set the `div` to `display:block` and show it.

However, I'm  having an issue doing so as the `display:block` never get's applied. I can do the reverese (`display:block` to `display:none`) . I'm guessing my issue is that I'm trying to apply a style to an element which does not exist on the page, if that is the case is there a way I can hide it, so that it takes up no space and show it when the screen is less than 450px?

Any help is much appreciated.

This is my `CSS`

```
#toplogo{
display: none;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

This is my `Media Query`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px){
#toplogo{
display: block;
}
}
```

This is the `HTML`

```
<div id="toplogo">
     <img src="/images/myimage.png"/>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're alternating between `#toplogo img` and `#toplogo`. Is this right?

Comment: use javascript instead

Comment: @MelanciaUK sorry no that was my mistake there, it should just be `#toplogo`. @Rasel, yes I might just do that, I just wanted to see if there was a way of doing it through CSS

Comment: It seems to work fine? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/vvpvhmqc/

Comment: Hmmm, I see that. Weird....must be something going on deeper in my stylesheet

Comment: might be worth (if its not huge) to post the full css file, might be an ordering issue

Comment: Inspect the element using your browser dev tools and check for the styles being applied to it.

Comment: Yep, that fixed my issue. I used the inspector. I noticed that it wasn't applying the style but was picking up the media query. I just added `display: block !important` and the issue was resolved. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Is your media query evaluated before the other CSS?

Comment: The use of `!important` should be avoided at all costs. Sometimes it's inevitable, I know. Try to track down the order your styles are being applied and re-order them accordingly.

Comment: try adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to your <head>, maybe your device isn't reacting to the page being responsive at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems just fine right now.

But I'd suggest mobile first approach, so the global style is aimed at mobile devices and later altered for bigger screens. Be sure to check what are you altering with your css  media queries and check your code order so you are not overwriting media queries with your styling later in the 'global' css code

This snippet below wont work as intended if my media query will be placed at the top of css file, as it will be later overwritten - [example of badly organized css media query](http://jsfiddle.net/gfuunyak/5/)

Working example

```css
/* mobile first approach */
#toplogo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

.hey {
    display: none
}
@media screen and (min-width: 450px){
    /* hide block when window width is at least 450px */
    #toplogo {
        display: none;
    }
    .hey {
        display: block
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="toplogo">
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png">
</div>

<div class="hey">Hey, I'm bigger than 450px!</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gfuunyak/4/

Answer (score 1):

No need to apply any js.

Your css & media query are perfectly written; It works in my end; if not work in your end; then just add !important after display: block;

Comment: adding !important should be the last thing to consider using css. rather check with your dev tools if any rule is overwriting your own.

Comment: This was in fact the solution, I'm just wondering @danielwinter why !important should be the last thing to consider? Is it labelled as bad practice?

Comment: Yes. Using !important should only be used in emergencies like when your style gets overwritten inline. Typically this is a problem of nested selectors (for example IDs are hard to overwrite, which is why you should only classes for styling and IDs for javascript interaction, according to SMACSS and several other dogmas). If you inspect your element using dev tools you can see exactly why it was overwritten by which rule. If you provide a live link I could show you which one might be the problem.